# Install Python / Matlab libraries without admin priviledges?

Tags: python, r, matlab, installation, administrator

A problem I frequently run into when using Python, R, Matlab etc. is installing packages or libraries when I don't have admin privileges on the server I'm using. I was wondering if there is a way to get around this?

I was thinking of "installing" the libraries somewhere in my own account, and adding that directory to my path, rather than somewhere like /usr/bin, /usr/lib etc. Does anyone have any tips / pointers on this? This must be a frequent problem for college / graduate students.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), that should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 4):

For R you can do install.packages("foo",lib="~/R/") - create the directory ~/R/ first - and then the packages will install there. Then do library(foo,lib="~/R/") to load it.

You can use the .libPaths function in your R startup files to add this automatically. Most of the Ubuntu boxes I've used are set up something like this by default. If a plain user tries to install a package it goes into their ~/R/ library, if root tries to do it, it goes into a site library for everyone.

Since generally there's no point backing up these installed packages, I tend to put my ~/R/ library on a non-backed up part of my filesystem.

[Note the correct use of 'library' here - in R-speak a library is a place where packages are installed]

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab you typically can just download the m files anywhere you like, and then add their location to the path. Not sure but I would suspect that getting a complete toolbox may require admin rights but for anything less you should be fine.

To conveniently add the location to your path automatically when you run matlab you can `edit startup.m`

Answer (score 0):

In python you can do `python setup.py install --user` or `pip install --user foo`.  This will install it in a user-specific directory appropriate for your platform.